# Regex match a message containing 'a' or 'an'

Tags: php, regex

Okay, here's the input message:

> You have an ear
>   You have an ice cube
>   You have a dog
>   You have an apple
>   You have a rock

I'm trying to get an output like this:

> ear
>   ice cube
>   dog
>   apple
>   rock

How can I accomplish this?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<?php
$str = $_POST["txtarea"];

preg_match_all('/You have (a|an) (.*)/', $str, $matches);
array_shift($matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $child) 
{
    echo $child;
}

?>
```

The whole (a|an) part is not working.

Comment: What do you mean but "is not working"? It perfectly works http://ideone.com/qNbuP8

Comment: Oh I see what my problem is now!  It looks like all the stuff I need is in the 2nd index (1) of $matches.  So, instead of foreach($matches[0]...), it should be foreach($matches[1]...).    Create an actual answer and I'll check-mark it.  Thanks zerkms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your matches are in the `$matches[2]` element.

`0` - is the whole matched string
`1` - the first group (`a|an` in your case)
`2` - the required group

To exclude a group you migh use `?:` hint, like `(?:a|an)`

PS: for "a or an" match it's actually possible to use `an?` which doesn't require parentheses

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = 'You have an ear
You have an ice cube
You have a dog
You have an apple
You have a rock';

preg_match_all('/You have (a|an) (.*)/', $str, $matches);

foreach($matches[2] as $child) 
{
    echo $child;

}
```

You are iterating wrong element of array